Use Excel data to populate a template in Word. How to collate all documents of the same "Talent Applied 1" into one documents
I'm working on an Excel VBA code to create Word documents from Excel data. The documents should be saved as Basketball.doc, Choir.doc, TableTennis.doc, and so on. However, the current VBA code creates files like Basketball.doc but only includes one student's data. It then attempts to save the next student under the same filename, causing an error.
Ideally, I want each file (e.g., Basketball.doc) to include all students in Basketball, formatted according to the Word template. I tried using ChatGPT but couldn't get the output as expected.
The screenshot of my excel file :Excel file data
The screenshot of the word template with placeholder enclosed with this <<  >>
Word Template
Screenshot of expected word document created say for example Basketball.doc:
Example: Basketball has 2 members
here's the code in the excel file:

Sub ReplaceText()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
Dim custN, path As String
Dim r As Long
r = 2
Do While Sheets("DSA-Sec Sch Applicants Detail").Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

wApp.Visible = True


Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\S1234567D\Downloads\DSA\Collated DSA.dotx", ReadOnly:=True)
With wdoc
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<MAIN CONTACT>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<NAME>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<TALENT APPLIED 1>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<DSA Date>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<DSA Day>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<DSA Time>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<TALENT APPLIED 1>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Perform Task>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7).Value
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    custN = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
    path = "C:\Users\S1234567D\Downloads\DSA\"
    .SaveAs2 Filename:=path & custN, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
End With
r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub


I would greatly appreciate assistance from experts in modifying the code to generate individual Word documents for each "Talent Applied 1," including all students' details filled into the template for that "Talent Applied".

Have you cosidered just copy-pasting the whole table at once instead of one row at a time? This article shows a way you can do that.

The problem is we have to follow the template format.  Hence if the excel data is large,  it is tough to do it one by one filling up all the placeholders <<>> .  So was thinking whether it is possible the export data to the create word document for each "Talent Applied 1"  that has all the members in .  E.g.  here Basketball has 2 members

From your description it sounds as though using MailMerge from Word with your Excel workbook as a data source would be more appropriate.

You can insert a table inside a template Word document and preserve the formatting by modifying the code available in this article by TheSpreadsheetGuru.com.
Let's say you have this Word document:

And you have a table/range that you can generate using your data. Now, you want to paste that generated table into the Word template to replace the expression <<Table>>.
You could then use the code below after replacing the necesary values with the ones that apply to your computer/file:

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel table into a an existing Word file
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run 
'(VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
'ORIGINAL FROM: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com
'MODIFIED BY DECIMALTURN
Sub ExcelRangeToWord()
    
    Dim Tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'Copy Range from Excel
    '>>> This is where you need to define the range where the table you want to copy is located <<<
    Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range
    
    'Create an Instance of MS Word
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Is MS Word already opened?
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear
    
    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    
    'Open the template
    '>>> Make sure to provide a valid filepath <<<
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=VALUE_FILEPATH, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    'Copy Excel Table Range
    Tbl.Copy
    
    
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    WordApp.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Table>>"
    WordApp.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    
    WordApp.Application.Selection.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=True, _
        RTF:=False
    
    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
    WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    
EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub



You'll then get the desired replacement inside your template file like below. Note the use of WordFormatting:=True in the code to make sure to preserve the formatting from the Word document.

EDIT:
Regarding how to generate the table that will be pasted to the Word document, I'd recommend copy-pasting your data to another temporary sheet, delete unnecessary column and re-order the remaining columns in the order needed. Then you can use a filter to paste only the data you need to the Word file.
In this example, I'd be copying only the data for a single year instead of "Talent Applied 1", but you get the idea:

Sub ExcelRangeToWord2()

Dim Filters As Variant
'A list of all the unique possible values
Filters = Array("2013", "2014")

Dim Filter As Variant
For Each Filter In Filters
    ExcelRangeToWordWithFilter CStr(Filter)
Next Filter

End Sub

Sub ExcelRangeToWordWithFilter(Filter As String)

[...]


Here, ExcelRangeToWordWithFilter would be the same function as above, but you'd add a filtering step after assigning the Tbl variable:
    Tbl.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Filter

Also, ExcelRangeToWordWithFilter would need to have a SaveAs step at the end to make sure you don't try to add the table twice in the same document.

Sub ExcelRangeToWordWithFilter(Filter As String)
    
    Dim Tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'Copy Range from Excel
    '>>> This is where you need to define the range where the table you want to copy is located <<<
    Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range
    
    'Apply filter
    Tbl.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Filter
    
    'Create an Instance of MS Word
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Is MS Word already opened?
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear
    
    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    
    'Open the template
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=VALUE_FILEPATH, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    'Copy Excel Table Range
    Tbl.Copy
    
    
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    WordApp.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Table>>"
    WordApp.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    
    WordApp.Application.Selection.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=True, _
        RTF:=False
    
    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
    WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    
    '>>>> Add something to save the file here <<<<
    myDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=Replace(VALUE_FILEPATH, ".doc", "_" & Filter & ".doc")
    
    
EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub


RESULTS:



Looking at your "Example : Basketball has two members", it does not seem as if you want a multi-row table for each TALENT APPLIED 1. Your output looks exactly like the output of a Word Letter MailMerge for a single TALENT APPLIED 1.
A way to achieve that is actually to perform a sequence of Word MailMerges, where each merge performs a Letter type merge to an output document for a single TALENT APPLIED 1, at least if you are working with the Windows version of Word and Excel. On Mac it's harder to get this right. There are complications using this approach, so it may be simpler to avoid it, although I post further description below.
I think a model where you open the template once, then successively populate it with the values from each row of your sheet and add a copy to the end of an output document is probably the way to go. Here's some code. It's difficult to get this kind of thing right, so please regard it as an example based on what we know of what you have. If it doesn't work, please don't just post back "it doesn't work" (!) - try to identify the problem and work through it yourself.
One thing you may have to do here is work a bit harder at inserting the Perform Task text, as Word and Excel do rather different things with multiline texts.
Here's the code I have there are plenty of ways the code coud be improved!
Sub onedocperTALENTAPPLIED1()
Const mysheetname As String = "DSA-Sec Sch Applicants Detail"
Const mycolname As String = "TALENT APPLIED 1"
Const mysavepath As String = "C:\Users\S1234567D\Downloads\DSA\"
Const mytemplatefullname As String = "C:\Users\S1234567D\Downloads\DSA\Collated DSA.dotx"

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
Dim addsectionbreak As Boolean
Dim outputdoc As Word.Document
Dim r As Long
Dim CurrentTalent As String
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True
Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=mytemplatefullname, ReadOnly:=True)

' as a one-off, replace your placeholders by bookmarks, which are easier to restore
Call replaceplaceholder(wdoc, "<<TALENT APPLIED 1>>", "talentapplied")
Call replaceplaceholder(wdoc, "<<MAIN CONTACT>>", "maincontact")
Call replaceplaceholder(wdoc, "<<NAME>>", "name")
Call replaceplaceholder(wdoc, "<<DSA Date>>", "dsadate")
Call replaceplaceholder(wdoc, "<<DSA Day>>", "dsaday")
Call replaceplaceholder(wdoc, "<<DSA Time>>", "dsatime")
Call replaceplaceholder(wdoc, "<<Perform Task>>", "performtask")

r = 2
addsectionbreak = False
CurrentTalent = Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value
Set outputdoc = wApp.Documents.Add(mytemplatefullname)
outputdoc.Content.Text = ""
Do While Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""
  ' Locating/replacing the bookmarks is a bit slow, but modifying a copy of the original template
  ' is probably significantly simpler than modifying a document with a large number of tear-off copies of the template.
  
  ' You may need to process the .Value if, for example the .Value of a time is stored as a decmal value
   ' Probably quicker to loop through the bookmarks, compare them
   ' and take the appropriate action. But can try that another day.

  Call replacebms(wdoc, "talentapplied", CurrentTalent)
  Call replacebms(wdoc, "maincontact", Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 2).Value)
  Call replacebms(wdoc, "name", Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 3).Value)
  Call replacebms(wdoc, "dsadate", Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 4).Value)
  Call replacebms(wdoc, "dsaday", Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 5).Value)
  Call replacebms(wdoc, "dsatime", Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 6).Value)
  Call replacebms(wdoc, "performtask", Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 7).Value)
  
  ' copy the modified template text to the output
  If addsectionbreak Then
      outputdoc.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage
  End If
  outputdoc.Characters.Last.FormattedText = wdoc.Content.FormattedText
  
  r = r + 1
  If Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value = CurrentTalent Then
    addsectionbreak = True
  Else
    ' finished with this TALENT
    outputdoc.SaveAs2 _
      Filename:=mysavepath & CurrentTalent & ".docx", _
      FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, _
      AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    outputdoc.Close
    If Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then
       ' More TALENTS to process
      CurrentTalent = Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value
      Set outputdoc = wApp.Documents.Add(mytemplatefullname)
      outputdoc.Content.Text = ""
      addsectionbreak = False
    End If
  End If
Loop
wdoc.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set wdoc = Nothing
wApp.Quit savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub replaceplaceholder(doc As Word.Document, PlaceholderText As String, BookmarkNameStem As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Word.Range
i = 0
Set r = doc.Content
With r.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = PlaceholderText
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = False
  While .Execute(findtext:=PlaceholderText, Forward:=True, Wrap:=False, Replace:=False)
    i = i + 1
    r.Text = ""
    r.Bookmarks.Add BookmarkNameStem & CStr(i), r
  Wend
End With
  
End Sub

Sub replacebms(doc As Word.Document, BookmarkNameStem As String, CellText As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim bmname As String
i = 1
bmname = BookmarkNameStem & CStr(i)
Do While doc.Bookmarks.Exists(bmname)
  With doc.Bookmarks(bmname).Range
    .Text = CellText
    .Bookmarks.Add bmname
  End With
  i = i + 1
  bmname = BookmarkNameStem & CStr(i)
Loop

End Sub

Here is some detail on the "Do it as a MailMerge" approach.
To do that, you would need to modify your Word template so that your placeholders <<NAME>> etc. are actually MailMerge MERGEFIELD fields. The Word document does not need to be a .dotx and it may be better to make it a .docx.
But for the field codes, you need to replace, e.g. the text
<<NAME>>

by the field code
{ MERGEFIELD NAME }

where the {  } are the special field code braces you can insert using ctrl-F9
For column names containing spaces you will need to use underscores _ instead of spaces, e.g. replace
<<TALENT APPLIED 1>>

by the field code
{ MERGEFIELD TALENT_APPLIED_1 }

Also, make sure you preserve the case of the letters in your column names, so use DSA_Day, not DSA_DAY.
Then your code needs to be more like the following. I've tried to keep it as similar to your code as possible, but for example you only need to create the Word object and open the template once. Unfortunately, trying to step through this kind of code in the VB Editor tends to cause problems. I would (a) always save your Excel file before each test and (b) either let the code run to completion, or set breakpoints at useful points in the code and always run to the next breakpoint rather than stepping.
Sub onemergeperTALENTAPPLIED1()
' Put some text values in Constant definitions
Const mysheetname As String = "DSA-Sec Sch Applicants Detail"
' This is the actual Excel column name, not the modified name needed by WOrd.
Const mycolname As String = "TALENT APPLIED 1"
Const mysavepath As String = "C:\Users\S1234567D\Downloads\DSA\"
' Your Word template, except I've made it a .docx
' mmmd = Mail Merge Main Document
Const mymmmdfullname As String = "C:\Users\S1234567D\Downloads\DSA\Collated DSA.docx"

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
' NB,
' Dim custN, path As String 
' means custN is an Object, not a String. 
' So do it like this
' Dim custN As String, path As String
' or this
Dim custN As String
Dim path As String
Dim r As Long
' save the TALENT text so we can tell when a new one begins
Dim CurrentTalent As String
r = 2
CurrentTalent = Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True
Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=mymmmdfullname, ReadOnly:=True)
With wdoc.MailMerge
  .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
  .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
  Do While Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""
    ' The SQL statement would look like this. Note the $ at the end of the Sheet name.
    ' SELECT * FROM [DSA-Sec Sch Applicants Detail] WHERE [TALENT APPLIED 1$] = 'Basketball'
    .OpenDataSource Name:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM [" & mysheetname & "$] WHERE [" & mycolname & "] = '" & CurrentTalent & "'"
    .Execute
    ' After a Mail Merge Execute, the ActiveDocument is the merged document.
    ' NB, you may need to ensure that the TALENT APPLIED 1 text only contains characters that are valid in a file name/
    wApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 _
      Filename:=mysavepath & CurrentTalent & ".docx", _
      FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, _
      AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    wApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    ' Move to the next TALENT APPLIED 1 or end of data
    Do While (Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value <> "") And (Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value = CurrentTalent)
      r = r + 1
    Loop
    CurrentTalent = Sheets(mysheetname).Cells(r, 1).Value
  Loop
End With
wdoc.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set wdoc = Nothing
wApp.Quit savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub

